# How do I plot the gPRC error ratio via MQL on a Cumulative duration metric with Opentelemetry data exported to Google Monitoring

Tags: metrics, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a `workload.googleapis.com/rpc.server.duration` metric exported by [opentelemetry-operations-go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-go) and it is a CUMULATIVE type of metric

[image]

How do I plot the error ratio via MQL?

I know I could plot request rate like this

```
fetch generic_task
| metric 'workload.googleapis.com/rpc.server.duration'
| count_from
| rate
| group_by [metric.rpc_method, resource.location],
    [value_duration_aggregate: sum(value_duration_count_from)]
| every 1m
```

But I got stuck on how to plot a ratio of the requests that has status as not OK?

I tried it like this

```
fetch generic_task
| metric 'workload.googleapis.com/rpc.server.duration'
| count_from
| rate
| filter_ratio_by [metric.rpc_service, resource.location], metric.rpc_grpc_code != 'OK'
| group_by sliding(5m), sum(val())
| condition val() > .05 '10^2.%'
```

But the plotted results seem far from what I expected them to be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was quite close but I need to change the order between
the `group_by` and `fitler_ratio_by` operation.

So this works:

```
fetch generic_task
| metric 'workload.googleapis.com/rpc.server.duration'
| count_from
| rate
| group_by sliding(5m), sum(val())
| filter_ratio_by [metric.rpc_service, resource.location], metric.rpc_grpc_code != 'OK'
| condition val() > .05 '10^2.%'
```

More details can see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-go/issues/528#issuecomment-1322730906)